# applyTheme via Javascript in SharePoint

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api

I'm trying to apply a theme in another site collection via JSOM and REST.
I get a 404, that the file is not found. It doesn't matter if i choose another spcolor or spfont file. The result is still the same.

What am I doing wrong?

```
var applyTheme = {
url: urlToSiteCollection + "/_api/web/applytheme(
colorpaletteurl='/_catalogs/theme/15/palette007.spcolor',
fontschemeurl='_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme007.spfont',
backgroundimageurl='/piclibrary/th.jpg', 
    sharegenerated=true)",
                                type: "POST",
                                headers: {
                                    "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                                    "X-RequestDigest": digest

                            },
                            contentType: "application/json;odata=vebose",
                            success: function (applyThemeData) {
                                alert("Applyat theme");
                            },
                            error: function (ex) {
                                alert(JSON.stringify(ex));
                            }
                        };
$.ajax(applyTheme);
```

And the JSOM code:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(urlToSiteCollection);
        var web = clientContext.get_web();
        var colorPaletteUrl = urlToSiteCollection + "/_catalogs/theme/15/palette011.spcolor"; 
        var fontSchemeUrl = urlToSiteCollection + "/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme002.spfont";
        var backgroundImageUrl = imageUrl;
        var shareGenerated = true;

        web.applyTheme(colorPaletteUrl, fontSchemeUrl, backgroundImageUrl, shareGenerated);
        web.update();

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(onApplyThemeSuccess, OnFailure);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely you are getting this error since the endpoint:

```
http://<sitecollection>/<site>/_api/web/applyTheme(colorPaletteUrl,fontSchemeUrl,backgroundImageUrl,shareGenerated)
```

expects values for `colorPaletteUrl`,`fontSchemeUrl`,`backgroundImageUrl` parameters to be specified as *server relative url*, for example: `/<site server relative url>/_catalogs/theme/15/palette007.spcolor`

The following example works for me

```
var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl;
var options = {
   colorpaletteurl: _spPageContextInfo.siteServerRelativeUrl + '/_catalogs/theme/15/palette007.spcolor'
};


applyTheme(siteUrl,options)
   .done(function (result) {
          console.log("Theme has been applied");
   })
   .fail(function (ex) {
         console.log(JSON.stringify(ex));
   });
```

where

```
function applyTheme(siteUrl,parameters){
    var requestUrl = siteUrl + "/_api/web/applytheme(";
    var paramUrls = [];
    for(var p in parameters) {
        paramUrls.push(p + "='" + options.colorpaletteurl + "'");
    }       
    requestUrl += paramUrls.join(',') +  ")";     
    return $.ajax({url: requestUrl,
                   type: "POST",
                   headers: {
                     "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
                     "X-RequestDigest": $('#__REQUESTDIGEST').val()
                   },
                   contentType: "application/json;odata=vebose",
   });
}
```

Comment: It's working now, Vadim. Thank you!
I don't understand why the ajax function wont go into the success function and log. But, hey, when it works it works!

Answer (score 0):

When you create a new context using `SP.ClientContext(url)` the url parameter needs to point to a site within the current site collection. The SharePoint JavaScript client object model does not support access across different site collections.

An alternative would be to use REST or SharePoint's other web services to access the other site.

Comment: Well I have tried this principle. But I still get a 404 file not found:

I am using this url: https://sogetiumea-my.sharepoint.com/personal/simonagren_sogetiumea_onmicrosoft_com/_api............

`$.ajax({
  url: "http://<site url>/_api/web
    /applytheme(colorpaletteurl='/_catalogs/theme/15/palette011.spcolor',
        fontschemeurl='/_catalogs/theme/15/fontscheme007.spfont',
        backgroundimageurl='/piclibrary/th.jpg', sharegenerated=true)",
  type: "POST",
  headers: { "X-RequestDigest": <form digest value> },
  success: successHandler,
  error: errorHandler
});`